# Is it possible to put value's in a ascending order to a tagg

Tags: javascript, jquery

So lets say you get 3 value's back from a command

```
6 
8  
9
```

and you have 3 elements in your page

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

is it possible in javascript/jquery to put the value into a the P tagg in a ascending order without putting any ID's or classes tot he P tagg.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Take the time to read "[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// lets say you have values in an array
    var values = [6,8,9];
    var $tags = $('p');
    $tags.each(function(index, item){
      $(item).text(values[index]);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

If I understood your requirement, the above code works

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. See this example: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

For example: `$("p").eq(1).text(1)`

Comment: Intereseting, didn't know that exist should play around a little for trying to get the result I want. thanks!